# How to disable Esc button event on alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show an `alert` message on button click. After pressing OK of the alert popup I am going to do further processing.

It's the expected flow, but when user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button then also without clicking on OK my page goes to further processing. I want to restrict this flow i.e. restrict the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button event but I can't find any way to do this.

```
var keynum

if (window.event) { // For IE
  keynum = e.keyCode
} else if (e.which) { //For netscape Mozilla Firefox
  keynum = e.which
}

if (keynum == '113' && saleFlag == true) {
  var totalQty = document.getElementById('totalQty').textContent;
  var totalAmt = document.getElementById('totalAmount').textContent;

  alert("You Played Total Qty: " + totalQty + " of Rs. " + totalAmt);    
} else if (keynum === '27') {
  return false;
}
```

but alert message is still closed .

I want alert message as it is which is open on 113 keycode event.

Comment: Simple answer, you can't. It's controlled by the OS at a level lower than JS has access to. If you want to block access until the OK button is explicitly clicked then you would need to use a third party library which adds modal popups in HTML instead of using `alert()` - although note that these are even more trivial to bypass.

Comment: Maybe use `confirm` instead..    `while (!confirm("continue"));`

Comment: the problem is that your javascript is ignored when the alert is shown. It blocks the execution, so no js code will be ran

Comment: @Keith I have also tried this but confirm also closed !

Comment: This is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should be looking into how to structure things such that the escape key doesn't interfere, not how to stop the escape key from working. Moreover, please don't use alerts...it's super bad practice to begin with for technical reasons, it's also super aggravating user experience.

Comment: @AbhijeetKale  It closes, but only for it to re-open again, until you click ok.  That's the best your going to get with the browsers built in dialogs.  Like Rory pointed out, you'll have to either roll your own, or using something like Twitter Bootstrap modal's..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks I understand your point try it by using 3rd party library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with `alert()` is that it will always return `undefined`, giving you no indication of what was pressed. Instead, you can use `confirm()` which will allow you to display a similar sort of popup.

However, the advantage of `confirm` is that it returns a `true` if you clicked "OK" on the popup and `false` if you pressed <kbd>esc</kbd> or "cancel".

Thus, using `confirm` you can use a `do-while` loop to keep popping up your popup until the user has pressed "OK" (or pressed the <kbd>enter</kbd> key)

See example below:

```js
let res;
do {
  res = confirm("Popup");
} while(!res);
```

Using the native confirm/alert box isn't a good user experience as it freezes the UI thread. If you can avoid it, I suggest using the DOM to open popups/modals built through HTML. This can easily be done by using a library.

Comment: This is certainly one workaround, but from a UX perspective it's really not a good solution. You're forcing someone to click OK. You cannot dismiss the dialog by clicking cancel, therefore the cancel button is an annoyance to your users. This logic is also often caught by website trustworthiness checks and will hinder your result.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I agree, it's definitely not a solution which I would necessarily use in a professional matter. For something like that I would consider using a jQuery/3rd party plugin such as swal.

Comment: @NickParsons thanks it solve my issue but I know it is not the recommended way and also unnecessary shows cancel button. I will definitely try it by using 3rd party library .

Comment: OK thanks ... are you interested? If not, no worries. Thanks for reading.

Comment: @Crashalot I’ll have to look into it a little. But currently I’m pretty busy this year so not sure if I’ll be able to do it :/

Comment: Don't use alert in the first place. You can always use modal to create a popup to request for confirmation. It's better that way

Comment: Unfortunately, `esc` returns `true` with confirm dialog with node.js/electron.